# Selenium 2 WebDriver: How to verify that an image request has been received and fulfilled?

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver

Is there a good way to check that a GET request for an image, something like https://api.google.com/v1/__x.gif, has been received & fulfilled in Selenium 2 WebDriver with php?

Initially I thought that I could make an XHR request and alert() the responseText, using assertEquals to compare my expected string to the actual output. Quickly realized this wasn't going to work, since I wanted to see the page's network requests that I'm testing.

After more research, I found two very different possibilites:

- First being captureNetworkTraffic (pending response from Sauce Labs support to see if this is possible):
- The second option (which I don't completely understand) would be setting up a proxy server.

I'm new to stackoverflow and a beginner when it comes to server requests. Thank you for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 and 2 are the same; you use a proxy to capture network traffic.

When creating a driver instance in Webdriver, you have the ability to set a proxy. This is a server and port through which the browser will direct all network traffic. Proxies can do many things such as creating mock responses, manipulating requests etc, but in your case, you want the proxy to record the request made, forward on to the required server, record the response, and return response back to browser.

If you use a proxy like Browsermob, you can interrogate the requests during the test run as the proxy has an API (e.g get me the latest request the browser made and assert it was a POST)

There appears to be a PHP library to wrap interaction with the Browsermob instance https://packagist.org/packages/chartjes/php-browsermob-proxy

So, in your test;

- Start proxy
- Create driver using the proxy setting
- Go to required page
- Assert that request was made in Browsermob

Of course, the other simpler approach could be to get the image src url from the html via seleniuml, then make a GET request in the test using a http client. If it returns an image, then you can say that the url from the ing tag works , and that may be good enough for your testing.

Comment: Thank you, Robbie. I was hopelessly lost on this and am now making more sense of your explanation.

Comment: If you feel it covers your question, please accept the answer